# Sum of dependent R.V

Tags: random-variable, density-function, convolution

I have two random variables whose PDF are parameterized by an unknown constant as follows:

P(A;d)
P(B;d)

apparently, these two are not independent, so to find P(A+B;d) one cannot use convolution.

1- Do you have any idea how to procede?

2- is my statement about independence correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you can no longer use convolution.

If your random variables are now dependent, then in order to know the PDF of their sum you need to know their joint PDF [$P(A,B;d)$ according to your notation].

Once you know this, look at this question:

[How to add two dependent random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables)