# Extend bivariate to multivariate convolution formula?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, convolution

In reference to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables), the pdf for dependent random variables $X_1+X_2$ is given by:

$$f_{X_1+X_2}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1,X_2}(x,z-x) \mathrm dx$$

How does this formula extend to the multivariate case $f_{X_1+...+X_n}(z)$?

Comment: It's immediate from $X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1}+X_n = (X_1+\cdots+X_{n-1})+X_n$, leading to a recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's follow Dilip Sarwate's instructions in [the post you reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21561/919):

> ... the formula is obtained by writing $F_{X_1+X_2}(z)$ as a double integral of the joint density function over the specified region and then "differentiating under the integral sign."

Let the joint density of random variables $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ be given by $f$.  Then, by definition, the density of the sum $X=s(X)=X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$ is

$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X \le x) = {\int \cdots \int}_{s(\mathbf x) \le x} f(\mathbf x)d\mathbf x.$$

Assuming $F_X$ is differentiable at $x$, it has a density there given by

$$f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_X(x).$$

To obtain a formula like the quoted one, apply [Fubini's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to express $F_X$ as a repeated integral,

$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{x-(x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n)}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n,$$

[differentiate under the integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign), and apply the (first) [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) to obtain

$$\eqalign{
f_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{x-(x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n)}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) dx_1\right) dx_2 \cdots dx_n \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-(x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n),x_2,\ldots,x_n) dx_2 \cdots dx_n.
}$$

Any of the variables can play the role of $x_1$, yielding $n$ formulas for the sum.

---

Alternatively, define $Y_{i} = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_i$ and apply the two-variable formula (as written just above for the case $n=2$) recursively via the relation

$$Y_i = X_1+\cdots+X_{i-1}+X_i = (X_1+\cdots+X_{i-1})+X_i = Y_{i-1}+X_i$$

for $i=n, n-1, \ldots, 2$ to obtain

$$\eqalign{
f_X(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y_{n-1},X_n}(x-x_n, x_n) dx_n \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y_{n-2},X_{n-1},X_n}(x-x_{n}-x_{n-1}, x_{n-1}, x_n) dx_{n-1} dx_n  \\
&\cdots \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdots \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-x_n-x_{n-1}-\cdots-x_2,x_2,\ldots,x_n) dx_2 \cdots dx_n,
}
$$

giving the same result.

Comment: And what about $Y = X_1 + X_2$ where $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$ i.e. $X$ is a bivariate random variable and we want to compute a distribution of its sum $Y=\{y_1 ,y_2\}$ which is also bivariate?

Comment: @Confounded I cannot make sense of that, because I understand the sum of $X$ to be $x_1+x_2,$ which is univariate.

Comment: Let $\mathbf{X_1} = [X_{1,1}, X_{1,2}]$ be a bivariate RV (e.g., a bivariate normal with covariance $\Sigma$). Let $\mathbf{X_1} \sim \mathbf{X_2}$. How do we calculate the distribution of a random variable $\mathbf{Y}$ which is given by a sum of two bivariate RVs, i.e. $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X_1} + \mathbf{X_2} = [X_{1,1}, X_{1,2}] + [X_{2,1}, X_{2,2}] = [X_{1,1}+X_{2,1}, X_{1,2}+X_{2,2}] = [Y_1, Y_2]?$ What is the formula for the convolution in this case?

Comment: @Confounded Because $Y_1=X_{1,1}+X_{2,1}$ (and similarly for $Y_2$) it's the same formula.

Comment: But what about the joint distribution (pdf) of $[Y_1, Y_2]$? If we calculate separately for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, we only get their marginals, no?

Comment: @Confounded I'm sorry, I had imagined you were asking about expectations and they don't care about joint distributions.  To obtain the full distribution you use the multivariate generalization of the convolution.

Comment: Which I though what is thread was about since the title is "multivariate convolution formula"...

Comment: @Confounded A close look at the question itself reveals that "multivariate" is intended in the sense of finding the distribution of the sum of $n$ *univariate* variables.