# Sum of correlated negative binomials

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

Suppose $X, Y$ are non-independent random variables with $X\sim NB(r,p)$ and $Y\sim NB(s,p)$; correlation between $X$ and $Y$ is $<$ 1.

Is sum $X + Y$ distributed as negative binomial? Or not?

Comment: How can X+Y be distributed as negative-binomial? Negative binomial has positive probability for arbitrarily large numbers, where as $P(X+Y>r+s)=0$

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables

Comment: @Meet There are two kinds of negative binomials, one for "number of trials to the $r$-th success" and one for "number of *failures* to the $r$-th success". Under independence and given the same $p$, the sum of two negative binomials of the second type is negative binomial of that same type. See the two different sets of support [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)

Answer (score 2):

As stated your question doesn't specify enough information to give a definite answer.

In some situations the answer is "yes". In general the answer is "no".

An example of a situation where the answer is "yes" is as follows:

Let $W\sim \text{negbin}(n_w,p)$, $U\sim \text{negbin}(n_u,p)$, $V\sim \text{negbin}(n_v,p)$,  where $W,U$ and $V$ are all independent -- here we're talking about the parameterization in the sidebar to the right in the Wikipedia page on the [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Now let $X=W+U$ and $Y=W+V$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are each negative binomial but they're correlated (since $\text{cov}(X,Y) = \text{cov}(W+U,W+V) = \text{var}(W)+0+0+0$).

In general the distribution of $X+Y$ depends on their *joint distribution*, which you did not specify.